# How to get the exact rotation angles of a rotated 3D object in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

I would like to get the rotation angles created by the effect of an existing object (Undo is not possible):

**Effect -> 3D -> Rotate...**

Comment: If you havent expanded theobject then the effect is still live in the appearance panel. If you Have expanded then no its not easy.

Comment: Unfortunately it was already expanded and saved (no history available). But many thanks for your help. I will try to reconstruct the angles by sense of proportion.

Comment: Do you know the original shape?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use guidelines

You can rotate a guideline to measure the angle of the "effect" you specified. It is a crude solution but it is better than approximating.

To rotate a guideline:
[rotate guidelines](http://www.thegraphicmac.com/easily-create-guides-at-any-angle-in-adobe-illustrator)

Comment: It does not help since a 3D rotation is composed of 3 independent variables. And since you see a projection of it... Oviously if you konw 3 cardinal directions that really are orthogonal to each other then you can unpack the rotation form the matrix, if there is no perspective transform

Comment: Fortunately there were some orthogonal components and it worked by using guidelines. Thank you very much!